# a For loop with conditional statment within an array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, conditional-statements

Can please anyone help me, I tried different conditions but, constantlly I am creating and infinite loop, and I am not sure how to figure it out.

Using for loop structure how to add a conditional statement within the array that will loop through the array and determine which one is my favourite car

```js
const vehicles = ["Audi", "BMW", "Seat", "Opel", "Peugeot"]; 
let fav = "Seat" 
for (let i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++){
    console.log(`Not my fav ${vehicles[i]}`);
}
```

> The Audi is not my favourite vehicle
> The BMW is not my favourite vehicle
> The Seat IS my favourite vehicle
> The Opel is not my favourite vehicle
> The Peugeot is not my favourite vehicle*/

Sorry, I am just a beginner, I will really appreciate any hints or solutions to this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop you have to write:

```js
if (vehicles[i] == "Seat") {
    console.log("The Seat is my favorite vehicle");
} else {
    console.log("The ${vehicles[i]} is not my favorite vehicle.")
}
```

You can also create a list of favorite vehicles and check whether vehicles[i] is in the favorite vehicles list.

```js
var favorite_vehicles = ["Seat", "Audi", "ETC"]

for (let i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) {
    if (favorite_vehicles.includes(vehicles[i]) == true) {
        console.log("The ${vehicles[i]} is my favorite vehicle.")
} 
    else{
        console.log("The ${vehicles[i]} is not my favorite vehicle.")
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you just shortly explain why the code is only executed with var instead let/const ?? thanks again

Comment: I don't think let/const should be a problem. They should work as well.